# Converting height of ft inches to just inches

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has height stored in the following formats: examples: 5' 6"
,4' 10.5", 5' 3.75" How can I convert these to just inches in SQL Server?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: nothing yet. I know I need to use cast and somehow separate by the ', ., and " or use left and right functions

Comment: that's not what I am implying. I've spent the last half hour researching solutions. I suppose that does not count.

Comment: Can you tell me the logic for the conversion?

Comment: You should look at SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. Those two functions are the key to solving this.

Comment: I need to provide reporting to a health insurer and they need the format in inches. The EHR does not have a built in conversion in another table. I'm assuming I need to use the split function and then I can do (X (the amount before the ') x 12 + the amount after the ' and before the "

Comment: You could do it the way you just described.   Make the attempt, post the code, and we will help you debug it.

Comment: I received some insight from someone else on the same EHR. I will test this and see if it works. In the meantime I used the text to columns after export in excel and solved it in 2 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

What you should have done in the first place is storing the height as an decimal instead of a varchar(x) describing the height in inches. Then it would be easy to get the foot and inches(col/12 = foot, col%12 = inches).

Since you already messed up your data, here is a way to get the correct height

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(height varchar(15))
INSERT @t values
('5'' 6"'),
('4'' 10.5"'),
('5'' 3.75"')

SELECT 
  height,
  LEFT(height, charindex('''', height) - 1) * 12+ 
  CAST(REPLACE(STUFF(height, 1, 
    CHARINDEX(' ', height), ''), '"', '') as decimal(5,2)) inchheight
FROM @t
```

Result

```
height    inchheight
5' 6"     66.00
4' 10.5"  58.50
5' 3.75"  63.75
```

Comment: Could do without the condescension. Not everyone gets to choose how their data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Use string functions like `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`....

**Query**

```
select height, round((t.feet + t.feet2) * 12, 2) as inch from
(
    select height,
    left(height, charindex('''', height, 1) - 1) as feet,
    cast((replace(right(height, len(height) - (charindex(' ', height, 1) - 1)), '''''', '')) as decimal(8,5)) * 0.0833333  as feet2
    from tbl_Height
)t;
```

This might not be an efficient solution. 
But you can use this as a hint.

Comment: I've been successful getting the feet x 12 function as (see below - for some reason won't change to code format here) but I need the value of in between the ' and " for the total inches value to add to the feet figure left(enc.height, charindex('''',enc.height)-1) *12

Comment: compounding this is the fact the field is varchar